# How is prediction done in live environment

Tags: r, algorithm, prediction

I am new to predictions and all I see is training data set and test data set. But actually how is a prediction model or an Algorithm run in live environment. We have millions of observations in real world. So how do we do that. Do we run the models on sample data or on all millions of rows.

Also, what ever changes are done on training set, is that to be done on test set. Meaning, if any changes are made for missing values or outliers in training set, is that to be replicated on test set as well?

Any help please.

Comment: Ideally, the model you build with test data can be directly used on real-world data.  If running time be a concern, then your trained model could be fit to a simpler model which runs faster.  Which machine learning method(s) are you planning to use?

Comment: **How used**: some save the model object to an `rdata` file and load it when needed for new data, but I'm sure there are other techniques out there. **Train/test**: yes, imputation or corrective action needs to be the same on both the training and test datasets (as well as data used for production predictions).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Will there be any variance in terms of accuracy when we run the model on real world data? I am just a beginner in ML and I am learning caret package. Any help on other useful ML methods please.

Comment: If you properly cross-validate your model, then ideally it should behave well against real-world data.